# Как составить SQl запрос с динамическим JOIN в зависимости от значения поля

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть три таблицы: `product`, `info`, `prop`

В таблице `product` в поле `type` хранится название таблицы, а в поле `type_id` хранится `id` строки из таблицы указанной в поле `type`:
Таблица `product`:

| id | type | type_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | info | 1 |
| 2 | prop | 1 |

Мне нужно джойнить таблицу указанную в поле `type` по условию `JOIN info || prop ON product.type_id = info.id || prop.id`.
Я могу сделать один запрос чтобы получить сначала таблицу из поля `type` и потом уже составить второй запрос с JOIN на нужную таблицу.
Подскажите, могу ли я это сделать в одном запросе?

Comment: *В таблице product в поле type хранится название таблицы, а в поле type_id хранится id строки из таблицы указанной в поле type* Вообще-то такую структуру нельзя назвать ни оптимальной, ни best practice. И в подавляющем большинстве случаев она не оправдана. Одна разреженная таблица более эффективна.

Answer (score 4):

Шаблон:

```sql
SELECT product.column,
       info.column info_column,
       prop.column prop_column,
       COALESCE(info.column, prop.column) joint_column
FROM product
LEFT JOIN info ON product.type = 'info' AND info.id = product.type_id
LEFT JOIN prop ON product.type = 'prop' AND prop.id = product.type_id
```